# select 1 row for each day between from to until date in sql db2

Tags: sql, date, db2

we have an old legacy table with our point system that looks like this:

| from date | until date | points monday | points tuesday | points wednesday | points thursday | points friday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6-12-2021 | 10-12-2021 | 10 | 30 | 20 | 15 | 5 |
| 13-12-2021 | 13-12-2021 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

now for power bi and our analytics, we want to create a select query that makes an result like this:

| date | points |
| --- | --- |
| 6-12-2021 | 10 |
| 7-12-2021 | 30 |
| 8-12-2021 | 20 |
| 9-12-2021 | 15 |
| 10-12-2021 | 5 |
| 13-12-2021 | 10 |

how can something like this be accomplished in db2?

thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can list all dates with a recursive CTE and then [DECODE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=functions-decode) the result of  [DAYOFWEEK_ISO](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=functions-dayofweek-iso) to set points

```
with table1 (fromdate, untildate, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday) as (
  values
  (date '2021-12-06', date '2021-12-10', 10, 30, 20, 15, 5),
  (date '2021-12-13', date '2021-12-13', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  ),
alldates (fromdate, untildate, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, points_date) as (
  select table1.*, fromdate as points_date from table1
  union all
  select fromdate, untildate, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, points_date + 1 day from alldates where points_date < untildate
)
select
  points_date, decode(dayofweek_iso(points_date), 1, monday, 2, tuesday, 3, wednesday, 4, thursday, 5, friday) points
from alldates
order by points_date
```